# Android APK split on drawable-v21

Tags: android, apk

I've been reading up on apk splitting, and I am tried to do this for drawable-v21, since android studio provides us with that folder. So I tried to just run the project with

```
android {
    ...
    splits {
        density {
            enable true
            exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi"
        }
    }
}
```

in my `build.gradle` to see what I would get. I got a lot of different screen sizes, but nothing for `v21`. Why is that?